# Check options in select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my `Angular` app, I have 2 select inputs as follows.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem.name" ng-options="item.name for item in items" />

<select ng-model="selectedSubItem.name" ng-options="subItem.name for subItem in selectedItem" />
```

The options in the second select is dependent upon the option selected in the first select. Once the form is submitted, the id's from `selectedItem` and `selctedSubItem` are extracted and submitted to the `API`. This works perfectly for creating a new record.

While retrieving an existing record, the API returns the id's of `selectedItem` and `selectedSubItem`. I use `resolve` in my `app.js` to populate the available options in both the `selects`.

I'm a bit confused on how to reuse the same view to check the options in both selects based on the id's retrieved from the `API` in the same view.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, after your route resolves on the update view you have:

- `selectedItem.id`
- `selectedSubItem.id`
- `items` collection

...and each `item` has a nested collection of `subItems`.

First, you need to loop through each item in your `items` collection until you find the one that matches `selectedItem.id`. Then, you need to loop through each of that item's `subItems` until you find the one that matches `selectedSubItem.id`.

If you're using `Underscore.js`, the [`findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) method works great for this. I'm sure lodash has something similar.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Is this the best practice?

Comment: It's your only option, unless you change your data model. When dealing with a collection, i.e. an array of objects, you can't do a lookup by id any other way. If you had a map, i.e. an object where key = id, value = item object, then you could do it differently.